# Angular 5 - http get with xml response

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

Newby needs help with error. I am requesting data via a http get request.  The data is in xml format.  I need to convert it to json for use in my Angular app.  When I run the following code I get a error in the console "TypeError this.http.get().map is not a function.

```
list() {
  return this.http.get(this.apiRoot).map(res => {
  let data;
  xml2js.parseString( res.toString, function (err, result) {
  console.dir(data); // Prints JSON object!
  data = result;       
  });
  return data;
  })
  .subscribe(data => { 
  console.log(data);              
  });  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the operator map for observables from rxjs.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the rxjs map operator. With your existing code you can do:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

You can also import the operator function itself. This is preferred. See: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...
  return this.http.get(this.apiRoot).pipe(map(res => {
```

If you're using the deprecated `HttpModule` instead of `HttpClient` you'll have to do an additional step to get the response text:

```
.pipe(
  map(res => res.text()),
```

If you're using `HttpClient` you won't need to do this.

---

Finally, since you're using `xml2js` which does not support Promises or Observables you will have to wrap the call to `.parseString` to add it to the observable stream. Fortunately, RxJS provides a wrapper function that does this for you: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback.

Here we use `switcMap` instead of `map` because `bindNodeCallback` returns an observable. `switchMap` will *flatten* it for us.

```
import { bindNodeCallback } from 'rxjs/observable/bindNodeCallback';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

function list() {
  return this.http
    .get(this.apiRoot)
    .pipe(switchMap(res => bindNodeCallback(xml2js.parseString)(res)))
    .subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Comment: He is using angular 5, he can't be using something different than latest HttpClient from angular/common/http.

Comment: @SamiAl90 are you sure? I think you can still install and import `@angular/http` even if you're using Angular 5. Regardless this doesn't have an impact on my answer since I cover both cases.

Comment: @Explosive Pills Thanks for the prompt and detailed reply. I am using Angular 5 and the latest HttpClient. I tried your 2nd example but i get an error "Expected 0 arguments but got 1" for this line of `bindNodeCallback(xml2js.parseString)(res)`